# What exactly goes wrong with this definition of a limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

What goes wrong when I define $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L}$ as $$ \forall \epsilon > 0, \forall \delta > 0; 0 < |x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$

Comment: That's only true when $f$ is constant, and that constant is $L$.

Comment: In words, you don't want $f(x)$ to be close to $L$ for points that are any distance from $c$, you just want them to be close to $L$ for points that are **sufficiently** close to $c$. So all that matters is that you can find **some** $\delta>0$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown quibble:  $f(x) = L$ if $x \ne c$ and $f(c) = M$.  Then $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = L$ by this definition as well.

Comment: It can't be true for *ALL* $\delta$ because if you make $\delta$ honkin' huge and $f$ isn't constant everywhere but at $x=c$ this can always be falsee.  Let $f(x_0)\ne L$.  Let $\delta > |x_0-c|$ and let $\epsilon < |f(x_0) - L|$.  This *cant* be true.

Comment: I adding that $c$ must be an accumulation point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What goes wrong?  Everything.

Let $f(x) = x^2$ and let $c = 2$

Claim $\lim_{x\to 2} x^2 \ne 4$.

Pf:  Let $\epsilon = 0.1$.  Let $\delta = 7$.

So if $x=6$ then $0 < |x-2| = |6-2| = 4 < \delta$.  But $|f(x) -4|=|36-4|=32 \not < 0.1 = \epsilon$.

So $\lim_{x\to 2}x^2 \ne 4$.

Very few functions and points *will* have limits.  I think only constant functions will.  Or functions that are constant everywhere but the value we are taking the limit toward.

====

You can't do it for *ALL* $\delta$.

If $x_0 \ne c$ and  $f(x_0) \ne L$ then we can take $\delta >|x-x_0|$ and $\epsilon < |f(x_0) -L|$. And then  you have .....

$|x-x_0| < \delta$ and $|f(x) - L| > \epsilon$.

So $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) \ne L$. Ever.  (Assuming $f$ has at least one point other that $c$ where $f(x) \ne L$.)

Comment: +1. For the OP: rephrasing a bit, fleablood pointed out that we can "get rid of $\delta$" so that your definition is equivalent to $$\forall \epsilon>0,\forall x\not=c(\vert f(x)-L\vert<\epsilon).$$ And that is clearly equivalent in turn to $$\forall x\not=c, f(x)=L.$$

Comment: True.  Although I imagine for one inexperienced enough to make $\forall \delta > 0$ error in the definition, s/he may be equally inexperienced enough to not immediately get that $\forall \delta >0$ is the same as "getting rid of it" (we can make it so large as to have $|x-c|<\delta$ have no significance) and to not notice that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon \iff f(x) = L$ (if $|f(x)-L|<K$ when $K > 0$ then if $|f(x)-L|\ne 0$ then $|f(x)-L| > 0$ and so $|f(x)-L|$ would be less than ... itself).

Answer (score 0):

You should have for every epsilon, there exist a delta such as...
Else it will not work. We need to pick one delta, and show that every epsilon > 0 is less than f(x0) - L, thus their distance goes to 0, and hence f(x) -> L for sufficiently small epsilon. Letting this be true for all deltas would result in that every two point in the domain will make the limit go to L, so it would make the function a constant.